# Python Django /w Microsoft Graphs - I keep getting value error "state missing from auth_code_flow"

Tags: python, django, microsoft-graph-api

Python Django /w Microsoft Graphs -

I'm following this Microsoft Tutorial for building Django apps with Microsoft Graph (using it on my existing Django webapp), and I am having an issue with authentication: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/python

I'm on the step 'Add Azure AD authentication' and, after implementing,
I hit the sign in button and enter credentials...and I keep getting value error  "state missing from auth_code_flow".

The "callback" method is only making it to result=get_token_from_code(request) and then fails.

Here is the get_token_from_code method:

```
def get_token_from_code(request):
  cache = load_cache(request)
  auth_app = get_msal_app(cache)

  # Get the flow saved in session
  flow = request.session.pop('auth_flow', {})

  result = auth_app.acquire_token_by_auth_code_flow(flow, request.GET)
  save_cache(request, cache)

  return result
```

What I'm trying to do is eventually access excel online from my webapp.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: `state` is oauth parameter that lets your app detect oauth request forgery. Looking at the docs it's stored in `request.session`. Did you use `get_sign_in_flow` before? Can you confirm that `request.session['token_cache']` exist?

Comment: You can read [section 4](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-4) of the RFC if you want to understand what's happening in the code

Comment: I implemented MSAL integration with an in-house app and deployed it (following this same tutorial), and am now getting occasional tracebacks with this same error.  Users are authenticating without issues though.

Comment: @jdhildeb are you able to still read and write to user's outlook calendars?

Comment: @albertrw I don't know if you're still working on it however I was debugging through the source code, the problem is in the signin method where it sets ```request.session["auth_flow"]``` This value is called in method ```get_token_from_code``` there the auth_flow data in session is none, the session is not carrying the variable, which is causing the problem

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I just had this issue and resolved it. It is one of these two things:

1. You are starting out at 127.0.0.1:8000 and then when you're redirected you're at localhost:8000, which is a different domain. The sessions aren't remembered from one domain to the other. The solution is to start out on localhost:8000 so that the session persists across login.
2. Your browser is using super-strict cookie settings. Microsoft Edge appears to default to this mode on localhost and 127.0.0.1. There is a lock or shield icon in or near your address bar that lets you relax the restrictions on your cookie settings.

Try one or both of these and you should succeed.

Comment: Yep, I just clicked on the link the example gave me which is 127.0.0.1, rather you should use localhost so the callback stuff works

Answer (score 7):

I'm a beginner coder, so i'm pretty sure im just circumventing around the error. But replacing the website URL with http://localhost:8000/# and re running it somehow got around the error. maybe that could be of some use.

Answer (score 2):

If you are running on chrome, rather than running application on http://127.0.0.1:8000 run it on http://localhost:8000, because chrome isn't saving the cookies when the ip address is being used.